# MBProgressHUD not showing from another class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiactivityindicatorview, mbprogresshud

I'm getting values from Parse Cloud by pressing a button. The code for getting the data data from Parse is in another class, but when I try to show the MBProgessHUD from that class it doesn't do anything.

No errors either.  However, if I do all in the same class, it works. Not sure how to display the progressHUD from another class on a specific view which is open at that time.

```
- (IBAction)testWeather:(id)sender {

     Reports * obje2 = [[Reports  alloc]init];
     [obje2 startGetting];
}
```

// in reports class

```
-(void) startGetting {



           Names= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Latitude= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Longitude= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [Names removeAllObjects];
    [Latitude removeAllObjects];
    [Longitude removeAllObjects];


    NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *CountyName = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"CurrentlySelectedCounty"];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Reports"];
    [query whereKey:@"County" equalTo:@"Universal"];


    //
    NSInteger countTotal= [query countObjects];
    NSString *totalVals = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (int)countTotal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:totalVals forKey:@"NumberOfSwamps"];
    //


    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"browsePage"];


    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:vc.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading Reports";
    [hud show:YES];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         [hud hide:YES];
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *obj in objects) {

                NSString *LastName = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"] ;
                NSString *Lat = [obj objectForKey:@"Latitude"] ;
                NSString *Lon = [obj objectForKey:@"Longitude"] ;


                // add values to array
                [Names addObject:LastName];
                [Latitude addObject:Lat];
                [Longitude addObject:Lon];

                [self getResults];

            }

        }

 else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

    }];
}
```

Trying another way...but this doesn't work either...even though HUD is running from the original class.

browse.m,

```
    if (myInt == 8){

            NSLog(@"\n \n Pressed the refresh icon for reports");
            [self removeAllAnnotations];


[standardUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"HUD_Switch"];   // to make sure switching on
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];

            [self HUDSwitcher];


            Reports * obje2 = [[Reports  alloc]init];
            [obje2 startGetting];
        }

-(void) HUDSwitcher{

    NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger myInt = [standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"HUD_Switch"];   // 0 for switched off     .... 1 for switched on

    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"browsePage"];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:vc.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Testing";
    [hud show:YES];


    if (myInt==0) {
        [hud hide:YES];
    }

}
```

reports.m

```
     [standardUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"HUD_Switch"];   // to switch on the HUD value

    browsePage * obje2 = [[browsePage  alloc]init];
    [obje2 HUDSwitcher];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         [standardUserDefaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"HUD_Switch"];


[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
         browsePage * obje2 = [[browsePage  alloc]init];

        [obje2 HUDSwitcher];
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *obj in objects) {

                NSString *LastName = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"] ;
                NSString *Lat = [obj objectForKey:@"Latitude"] ;
                NSString *Lon = [obj objectForKey:@"Longitude"] ;


                // add values to array
                [Names addObject:LastName];
                [Latitude addObject:Lat];
                [Longitude addObject:Lon];

                [self getResults];

            }

        }

 else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the new UIViewController `vc`, it is not in the current view stack, so if you display a progressHUD on its view it won't appear on the screen.

You should display the progressHUD from the view of the initial viewController.

One way to solve this would be with delegation like this:

```
- (IBAction)testWeather:(id)sender {
    self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading Reports";
    [hud show:YES];

    Reports * obje2 = [[Reports  alloc]init];
    [obje2 startGettingWithDelegate:self];
}

- (void)reports:(Reports*)report didFinishGetting
{
    [self.hud hide:YES];
}
```

In yourViewController interface in the .h file add this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MBProgressHUD *hud;
```

In Reports Class

```
-(void) startGettingWithDelegate:id<yourProtocol> delegate {

    Names= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Latitude= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Longitude= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [Names removeAllObjects];
    [Latitude removeAllObjects];
    [Longitude removeAllObjects];


    NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *CountyName = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"CurrentlySelectedCounty"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Reports"];
    [query whereKey:@"County" equalTo:@"Universal"];

    //
    NSInteger countTotal= [query countObjects];
    NSString *totalVals = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (int)countTotal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:totalVals forKey:@"NumberOfSwamps"];
    //

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        // Inform Delegate that finished loading
        [delegate reports:self didFinishLoading];

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
                NSString *LastName = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"] ;
                NSString *Lat = [obj objectForKey:@"Latitude"] ;
                NSString *Lon = [obj objectForKey:@"Longitude"] ;


                // add values to array
                [Names addObject:LastName];
                [Latitude addObject:Lat];
                [Longitude addObject:Lon];

                [self getResults];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

To do this right you should create a `@protocol` in Reports.h and make you viewController conform to it.

In Reports.h

```
@protocol ReportsProtocol
    - (void)reports:(Reports*) finishedLoading;
@end

@interface ...
.
.
.
```

In yourViewController.h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <ReportsProtocol>
.
.
.
```

Another solution can be using blocks. Its a little more complicated but cleaner.

Comment: can you please tell a little more about how to implement this protocol

Comment: Not yet, still trying.

Comment: It's probably wrong. First you can't use [hud hide:YES] in that method because it hasn't been declared.

Comment: Thats right, I was thinking of SVProgressHUD were you call Class Methods, not instante. Still, the main ideia in my answer is the use of delegation for controlling the hud in the first viewController and not in the class. Create a property in the first viewControler and store the hud. I'll change the code a bit.